# How to filter json into specific format (removing certain parts)

Tags: php, mysql, json, filtering

I'm converting MySQL to json and the output provides more than I want, so I want to filter it to a couple of values per a segment.

I've tried finding similar questions although haven't found something I really understand well enough that I can adapt for this specific use case.

Here's what I'm doing to generate the json

```
$rows = array();
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }

  $json_string = json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here is a sample of the output

```
[
    {
        "0": "1",
        "id": "1",
        "1": "2019-05-25 14:38:10",
        "timestamp": "2019-05-25 14:38:10",
        "2": "4",
        "category": "4"
    },
    {
        "0": "2",
        "id": "2",
        "1": "2019-05-25 14:38:15",
        "timestamp": "2019-05-25 14:38:15",
        "2": "3",
        "category": "3"
    }
]
```

What I want instead is something more like this

```
[
  {
    "category": "4",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-25 14:38:10"
  },

  {
    "category": "3",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-25 14:38:15"
  }
]
```

Comment: You can set your query just to return the fields that you require i.e. SELECT category, `timestamp` FROM myTable;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to get only these two columns in your output. Optionally, you may use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` constant to fetch a result row as an associative array.

```
<?php
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        "category" => $r["category"],
        "timestamp" => $r["timestamp"]
    );
}

$json_string = json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL query from

```sql
SELECT * ...
```

(or what ever your SELECT clause look like) to

```sql
SELECT category, timestamp ...
```

Then your PHP code could be a one-liner:

```php
$json_string = json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```